# Given How would I prove if BdU=(Cl U) − U, then U is open, where BdU denotes the boundary of U?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I use ***Cl* A** to denote **closure of A**.  I was given the following:  If **A ⊂ X**, the boundary of **A** is defined by the equation

**BdA = (*Cl* A) ∩ (*Cl* (X − A))**

Here is my proof:

Assume **BdU=(*Cl* U) − U**. By definition,

**BdU = (*Cl* U) ∩ (*Cl*( X − U))** ....(1)

Then, subsituting (1) into **BdU=(*Cl* U) − U**,

I get   **(*Cl* U) ∩ (*Cl* (X − U)) = (*Cl* U) − U**

**(*Cl* U) − U = (*Cl* U )  ∩ (X-U)** ... (2)

Substituting (2) into **(*Cl* U )  ∩ (*Cl* (X-U)) = (*Cl* U) − U**,

I get **(*Cl* U ) ∩ (*Cl* (X-U)) = (*Cl* U )  ∩ (X-U)**

**(*Cl* U )  ∩ (*Cl* (X-U)) = (*Cl* U )  ∩ (X-U)**  **⇒  *Cl* (X  − U) = X - U**

⇒ **X - U** is closed

⇒ **U** is open

Is the proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here, there is a short argument:

If $\partial U=\overline U\smallsetminus U$ then $\partial U=\overline U\cap U^c$ so $\partial U\subset \overline U$ and $\partial U\subset U^c$.

Now, if $p\in U$ then $p\notin U^c$ and hence $p\notin\partial U$.
This implies that exists a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N\cap U^c=\varnothing$, so
$$p\in N\subset U,$$
that is, any $p$ in $U$ is in its interior.